# Pass two variables in Javascript URL to update a dropdown based on the passed values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, drop-down-menu

How to pass two variables to JavaScript function to change the drop down list based on that values?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading category" />
</div>');
        $.get('loadb.php?date=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#time").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
    });
});

</script>
<div class="sub-page-left">
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <form id="myform" action="spotDate.php" method="post">
        <?php
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="NID" size="20" value="'.$NID.'"/>';
        ?>
        Choose Date: <select name="date" id="date" class="dropdown"><OPTION VALUE=0>Choose Date<? $option ?>
                <?php
                $q2 = "select DISTINCT(AvailableDate) from FreeTimeSlots where PASSLeaderID = $SID  and CourseID = $CourseID";
                $r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2);
                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2)) {
                    echo "<option value=\"" . $row2['AvailableDate'] . "\">" . $row2['AvailableDate'] . "</option>";
                }
                ?>
        </select>
        Time: <select name="time" id="time" class="dropdown"><OPTION VALUE=0>Choose Time<? $option ?>
        </select><br /><br />
```

this code works where I am passing only the date value, but I want to updated based on the date and the hidden ID !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    $.get('loadb.php?date=' + $(this).val()+'&nid='+$('#NID').val(), function(data) {
        $("#time").html(data);
        $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass also the hidden field in the url:
'loadb.php?date=' + $(this).val() + '&nid='+$("input[name=NID]").val()